# What Do the Colors of the Following Error Reflect?

Tags: visual-studio

> the javascript language service is processing your request in the background

This most annoying background service keeps coming while attempting to write JavaScript code in Visual Studio2015 and slows down development. As seen in the screenshots below, what are the interpretations of the different background colors?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I worked on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Blue means the IDE is in Editing / Design Time mode.

Orange means the IDE is in Debug mode (i.e. it is currently attached to another process)